# I cannot access STM32 DMA register when configuring it

Tags: stm32, dma, stm32f4, usart

I currently use standard peripheral library to write a driver that enable memory to USART6_TX  DMA transfer on a STM32 F407 ZGT6 chip. However, I tried for a long time but the initialization keeps on failing: DMA_GetCmdStatus always returns DISABLE. By using GDB, I found that after the DMA_Init try to write configuration into DMA register, DMA CR register remains 0. The DMA initialize code and execution are as follow:

```
void DMA_USART6_Init(char* DMA_Start_Pos, uint32_t DMA_Buffer_Size){
DMA_Buffer_Size_GV = DMA_Buffer_Size;
DMA_Start_Pos_GV = DMA_Start_Pos;
/*RCC config*/
RCC_AHB1PeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_DMA2, ENABLE);
/*DMA init*/
//DMA_DeInit(DMA2_Stream7);
DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream7, DISABLE);
while ((DMA_GetCmdStatus(DMA2_Stream7) == ENABLE)){}
DMA_StructInit(&DMA_InitStruct);

DMA_InitStruct.DMA_Channel = DMA_Channel_5;
DMA_InitStruct.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = USART6_BASE + 0x04;//(uint32_t)&USART6->DR;
DMA_InitStruct.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr = (uint32_t) dubuff;//(uint32_t) DMA_Start_Pos;
DMA_InitStruct.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_MemoryToPeripheral;
DMA_InitStruct.DMA_BufferSize = (uint16_t)sizeof(dubuff);//DMA_Buffer_Size;
printf("buffer size should be %d \r\n", (uint16_t)sizeof(dubuff));

DMA_InitStruct.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
DMA_InitStruct.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
DMA_InitStruct.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_Byte;
DMA_InitStruct.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
DMA_InitStruct.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;
DMA_InitStruct.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
DMA_InitStruct.DMA_FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMode_Disable;
DMA_Init(DMA2_Stream7, &DMA_InitStruct);
printf("data counter after init %d \r\n", DMA_GetCurrDataCounter(DMA2_Stream7));
}
```

for the ENABLE code

```
void DMA_USART6_Enable_DMA(char* DMA_Start_Pos, uint32_t DMA_Buffer_Size, int MB){
Max_Buffer = MB;

USART6_init_for_DMA();
DMA_USART6_Init(DMA_Start_Pos, DMA_Buffer_Size);
DMA_USART6_NVIC_Init();
DMA_ITConfig(DMA2_Stream7, DMA_IT_TC, ENABLE);
DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream7, ENABLE);
while ((DMA_GetCmdStatus(DMA2_Stream7) == DISABLE)){}//program stucked in this loop
}
```

for the USART6 code:

```
void USART6_init_for_DMA(void){
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;

RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_USART6, ENABLE);
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);

GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_USART6);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_USART6);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_6;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_7;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = 57600;//115200;
USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;

USART_Init(USART6, &USART_InitStructure);
USART_Cmd(USART6, ENABLE);
USART_DMACmd(USART6, USART_DMAReq_Tx, ENABLE);
}
```

and the GDB result:

[the value that should be written into DMA CR register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYO4w.png)

text in the picture 1:

```
367   DMAy_Streamx->CR = tmpreg;
(gdb) print tmpreg 
$7 = 167904576
```

[the DMA CR register remains 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX4UT.png)

text in the picture2:

```
371   tmpreg = DMAy_Streamx->FCR;
(gdb) print *DMAy_Streamx
$10 = {CR = 0, NDTR = 0, PAR = 0, M0AR = 0, M1AR = 0, FCR = 0}
```

Please tell me if there is anything I can provide about my problem or things I can try further...
Note: In the same program, my USART6 and GPIO works fine.

Comment: "register remains 0" usually indicates that the clock hasn't been enabled. Have you enabled the DMA clock?

Comment: @Codo typical problem. People using "magic" libraries often do not read the uC documentation.

Comment: @Brad What is the point of using dead SPL? Why do you use command line gdb?

Comment: @Codo I believe "RCC_AHB1PeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_DMA2, ENABLE);" had done the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am OP.
At the start, I have a feeling that it could be an obvious mistake and that's true.
It turns out that I should use RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd instead of RCC_AHB1PeriphResetCmd because OBVIOUSLY the later accessed RSTR (RCC Reset register) rather than ENR an thus clock is not enable (about that Codo is right).

Well, Hope guys whoever sees this question won't repeat this embarrass mistake ;(

Comment: Just for anyone else that finds this... if you are using CubeMX there is a known issue.
https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000Bmob3uSQA/dma-not-working-in-cubemx-generated-code-order-of-initialization

Answer (score 0):

When the desired stream is activated, the relevant registers can no longer be configured. Only in dual buffer mode can memory addresses 0 and 1 be updated according to the bit CT function. You must first deactivate the relevant channel and then apply the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, I believe "DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream7, DISABLE);" and "while ((DMA_GetCmdStatus(DMA2_Stream7) == ENABLE)){}" had done the job. Moreover, when the CR bit remains 0, it also means EN bit is 0, which says that the stream is not activated.

Comment: I suggest you check the source code created in the hall once. Maybe you realize an idea or an important point from it.
In the configuration, you have to proceed based on a series of specific steps and finally activate the channel by setting the EN bits. These arrangements can also be seen in the user manual of the chip.

Comment: The module contains three BUS. AHBmem  and AHBPer are used to transfer data in Bus-matrix and bus APB are used to access configuration registers. If you can't access any register, Bus APB may not be active yet. The module clock is not configured and you must first enable it through the corresponding register in RCC

Comment: I had check out reference manual (RM0090) and SPL description (UM1061). It seems that both documents only mention AHBmem/per bus in DMA chapter. Also in the RCC register session, all the bits in RCC_APBxENR are about CAN, SPI, Timer etc. Please inform me if there are other documents that mention how can I startup APB to access DMA register, I will be very appreciate.

Comment: please take a look on AN4031

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you mean. However I can't see in AN4301 there is any description suggest one should startup APB bus before setting up DMA CR register, i.e. DMA_Init() in SPL.

Comment: "using HAL_DMA_Init() function. Prior to
HAL_DMA_Init() the clock must be enabled for DMA through the following macros:
__HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE() or __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE()." UM1725 page 275

Comment: in __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE() it basically do this: "SET_BIT(RCC->AHB1ENR, RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA2EN);" I think that's exactly what "RCC_AHB1PeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_DMA2, ENABLE); " have done? (ref: stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.h line 421)

Comment: I have an idea.
Due to the fact that bit EN  in DMA_CR is reset, set one of the configuration registers that can write / read and then read this register again. If the written value of this register is read, it is possible to configure and the problem is something else. the APB Clock enabled for DMA.Of course, we have to check whether it is possible to issue any exception(such as a bus error EXC) if the peripheral clock is not active or not in STM32Fx.

Comment: As far as I can remember, bit EN is also reset to hardware by observing a transfer error or resetting the transfer counter to zero. Maybe in the configuration, for example, the size of the burst is incorrect .. Please check these error flags after setting the EN bit

Comment: I think that is what GDB exactly do. After DMAy_Streamx->CR = tmpreg; (the value in tmpreg is 167904576), the DMAy_Streamx->CR remains 0. Also, I had checked TEIF, FEIF, DMEIF and none of them set (Because DMA haven't been started yet...).